# Getting syntax error on psql command to connect to a Redshift database

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-ec2, psql

I'm connected via SSH into an EC2 machine and am trying to run a python script to connect to a Redshift database.

The command I'm using is

```
psql "host=clusterhost user=admin dbname=databasename port=1234"
```

I know it works because if I copy and paste it into the command line, it works. I also used the same command in a shell script and that worked. So I'm not sure why it's not working with the Python script. Do I need to add something else to make it work?

Here's the error output I'm getting:

```
File "test.py", line 3
psql "host=clusterhost user=admin dbname=databasename port=1234"
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Why do you think it'd work in a Python script? It is not Python code.

Comment: what are you actually trying to do in your script?

Answer (score 0):

The [`psql` command line tool](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html) is not a Python command. You need to run it on your *command line* instead.

You could run it *from* a Python script as a subprocess, by using the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(('psql', 'host=clusterhost user=admin dbname=databasename port=1234'))
```